Visas Inquiry (Albania & European country)
If I have a Schengen visa for duration of stay of 30 days, but validaty for 1 month and half. I decided to travel to Albania in between my duration of stay in Europe countries, will it be counted from the 30 days of duration of stay or they will not be counted as it is not a Schengen country?

Is it a single entry visa?

See how to read a Schengen visa sticker

No it is Mult visa
